# Animation conflict issue with another animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this LoaderView which grow with given value, I want add some highlight effect to it as well, So basically there is 2 deferent and separate animation happening, one for activeValue and one for the highlight. i did not combine them together because they are 2 deferent things, but my output of codes combine these 2 values together and destroys highlight effect. I am looking a solid answer for my issue to having this 2 animation works side by side.
The issue happens when i add value.

I want this view be usable in macOS as well, so there is a possibility user changes the Window size, then my view would be changed as well.

[image: Progress bar with shimmer effect]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: CGFloat = 50

    var body: some View {
        LoaderView(activeValue: value, totalValue: 100)
            .padding()

        Button("add") { value += 10 }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct LoaderView: View {
    let activeValue: CGFloat
    let totalValue: CGFloat
    let activeColor: Color
    let totalColor: Color

    init(activeValue: CGFloat, totalValue: CGFloat, activeColor: Color = Color.green, totalColor: Color = Color.secondary) {
        if activeValue >= totalValue { self.activeValue = totalValue }
        else if activeValue < 0 { self.activeValue = 0 }
        else { self.activeValue = activeValue }

        self.totalValue = totalValue
        self.activeColor = activeColor
        self.totalColor = totalColor
    }

    @State private var startAnimation: Bool = .init()
    private let heightOfCapsule: CGFloat = 5.0

    var body: some View {
        let linearGradient = LinearGradient(colors: [Color.yellow.opacity(0.1), Color.yellow], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)

        return GeometryReader { proxy in

            totalColor
                .overlay(
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(activeColor)
                        .frame(width: (activeValue / totalValue) * proxy.size.width)
                        .overlay(
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(linearGradient)
                                .frame(width: 100)
                                .offset(x: startAnimation ? 100 : -100),
                            alignment: startAnimation ? Alignment.trailing : Alignment.leading)
                        .clipShape(Capsule()),
                    alignment: Alignment.leading)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
        }
        .frame(height: heightOfCapsule)
        .onAppear(perform: { startAnimation.toggle() })
        .animation(Animation.default, value: activeValue)
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: startAnimation)
    }
}
```

Comment: The animation looks fine to me. What's the result that you want?

Comment: @aheze: Thanks, It is fine because we did not pressed add, after pressing add it get messed up. :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't the `.animations` it is that `.onAppear` is only called once, so your animation never restarts. `startAnimation` needs to be toggled when `activeValue` changes. The way your animation works, toggling `startAnimation` reverses the animation direction. Therefore, I set `autoreverses: true`. It is a compromise either way.

```
struct LoaderView: View {
    //Nothing changed in this portion
        .onAppear{
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                startAnimation.toggle()
            }
        }
        // The issue is that .onAppear() is only called once.
        .onChange(of: activeValue, perform: { _ in
            startAnimation.toggle()
        })
        .animation(Animation.default, value: activeValue)
        // As a side effect, changing startAnimation to opposite values reverses the animation
        // you have made, so setting autoreverses: true hides this.
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: startAnimation)
    }
}
```

Edit:

I apologize for not getting back to this sooner. The issue with the rubber band animation is because of the transition when the app firsts launches. To prevent this, you need to wrap your variable change in `.onAppear()` in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` with enough time for the view to load. Then when you start the animation, it works correctly.

Comment: Your code does not work, I would wish myself that users test the code before answering a question.

Comment: I tested it in Preview but not on the simulator. I have seen that before. It is fixable, but I will have to get to it later.

Comment: Corrected the code. See the edits.